# Installing puppet 3.8 master

Tags: couchdb, puppet, hiera

I'm trying to install puppet-server 3.8.7.

The problem is that the puppet-server automatically requires puppet, that requires puppet-agent, who supplies me only the newest version that fits puppet 4.x only (puppet-agent-1.5.2).

The

"yum install puppet-server"

Failed .

What can i do?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: The os is :Rhel 7.2

Comment: I do not see any puppet-agent rpms here: https://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7Server/products/x86_64/. You very likely have subscribed to multiple puppet repos instead of only the correct one.

Comment: Fixed it, you right!                   And what is the difference between puppetserver1.1 and puppet-server-3.8.7?

Comment: `puppetserver1.1` is probably an early version of the puppet-server after the company went to the new versioning scheme once puppet itself hit 4.0.